Comparing Columns best way
Hoping someone can help with the best way to achieve this.
I have a spreadsheet which has a list of names from one domain and various information in each column. I want to compare this with a list of names which is from another domain i have placed in another column. I want to search Column B which has the names and then search column J which has the other domains and place a match in Column H next to the corresponding name.
I have tried a few formulas etc but none seem to work or give me what i want. Vlookup, Index etc. So at a bit of a loss. I am looking to match the names up so i can see who has an account in Domain 1 and 2. I will admit im no excel expert with formula's.
Index was giving me the first name in Column J and second and so on down Column H. So it wasn't matching
=INDEX(J2:J16992,MATCH(B2,B2:B736,0))
Below is an example of the sheet and how it looks.
Data Example
Ideally looking to put in Column H a name which matches column B.
Thanks

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

=VLOOKUP(B2, J:J, 1, FALSE)

Here it looks for the value in cell B2 (target name) within Column J (the other domain). If it finds a match, it returns the corresponding name from Column J. The 1 refers to the column number in the range (J
) that you want to return (which is the same column in this case). The FALSE argument ensures that VLOOKUP looks for an exact match. Go to the first cell in Column H where you want the matched name to appear.
